Cleaner way to parse a PDF in Python
Looking to parse PDFs to glean relevant info.
Using pypdf and am able to extract text, but it's a bit of a slog formatting into something usable because it appears the PDFs are formatted and not straight text.
For instance, looking to extract 'Asset', 'Transaction Type' and 'Amount', from the table herein:
https://disclosures-clerk.house.gov/public_disc/ptr-pdfs/2020/20017693.pdf
If I'm not able to extract the table (headers and all), I'd like to extract the ticker (eg, '(CSCO)'), asset type (eg, '[ST]' here), transaction type (eg, 'S') and amount, individually.
The below gets me all the text to parse, but what I'm returning so far is kind of janky and wonder if there's a better way.
import pypdf
import io
import requests as re
import pandas as pd 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pickle 
import fnmatch
import re as rx

url = 'https://disclosures-clerk.house.gov/public_disc/ptr-pdfs/2020/20017693.pdf'

c = io.BytesIO(re.get(url = url).content)
pdf = pypdf.PdfReader(c)

text = ""

for page in pdf.pages:
   
    text += page.extract_text() + "\n"
    
substring = text.split("\n") 

holding = fnmatch.filter(substring, '*(*)*')
htype = fnmatch.filter(substring, '*[[]*[]]*')


Everything I've ever heard about PDF files makes it look like they're intentionally obfuscated.  Probably because of the way they came to be as an outgrowth of Postscript which is a full programming language.  Good luck.

@markransom PDF is not intentionally obfuscated, but tailored towards visual appearance. Originally, it was not meant to be parsed again. Just like an executable is not intentionally obfuscated, but still less readable than source code.

I've had luck extracting data from parsed PDFs using regex, as long as the format of the PDFs is nearly identical and you can find the right regex expression to reliably pull the data out. I wrote some regex to pull the data that you want out of the PDF that you supplied, but you'll have to try it against other PDFs that you want to parse and make corrections as necessary.
import re

# Use your code to turn the PDF into a single string called `text`

transactions = re.findall(r"(\([A-Z][\s\S]*?\$.*\$[,\d]+)", text)

This will give you a list where each item is all of the data pertaining to a transaction, starting with the ticker and finishing with the amount. The regex looks a bit complex, but is basically looking for an open parenthesis followed by a capital letter to start the match, and the second occurrence of a dollar-sign followed by numbers and/or commas to finish the match. In between, the regex will capture everything including linebreaks. Next, we can pull the specific pieces of data out of each list item.
patterns = {
    "ticker": r"\(([A-Z]+)",
    "asset_type": r"\[([A-Z]+)",
    "transaction_type": r"([A-Z]+) \(",
    "amount": r"(\$[-\$\d, ]+)",
}

transaction_data = []
for t in transactions:
    data = {}
    for key, pattern in patterns.items():
        data[key] = re.search(pattern, t).group(1)
    transaction_data.append(data)

print(transaction_data)
# [{'ticker': 'CSCO', 'asset_type': 'ST', 'transaction_type': 'S', 'amount': '$1,001 - $15,000'}, {'ticker': 'CMS', 'asset_type': 'ST', 'transaction_type': 'S', 'amount': '$1,001 - $15,000'}]

You can modify the patterns dictionary if you find that these patterns don't work with other PDFs that you want to parse. Good luck!

Adding to this: you might want the extraction_mode="layout" - https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html
